# DayJS formatting with duration plugin returns undefined when passing day, hour and minute

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dayjs

Using momentjs, it works perfectly fine - returning 13m:

```js
moment.duration(sg.time_played, 'seconds').format('d[d] h[h] m[m]')
```

And with DayJS:

```js
dayjs.duration(sg.time_played, 'seconds').format('d[d] h[h] m[m]')
```

It would return the following string: `undefinedd undefined 13m`.

The expected output from both functions is `13m` and wasn't entirely sure why the DayJS plugin wasn't working like moment's.

Thanks.

Comment: `moment.duration()` doesn't have the `.format()` method, how is it possible that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `H` and `D` instead `h` and `d` like that:

`dayjs.duration(seconds, 'seconds').format('D[d] H[h] m[m]')`